# how to print the error in a let-else statement in rust?

Tags: rust

I prefer to use let else statements because it removes nesting in the code

```
let Ok(result) = function_call_that_returns_a_result() else {
   return "error message".into();
}
```

However, if I were to use an if let, else or match statement, I could get access to the actual error message inside.

```
if let Err(err) = function_call_that_returns_a_result() {
  return format!("Error: {}", error).into();
}
```

Is there an easy way to avoid using the 2nd method? Because if I use it like this, I get extra nesting.

```
if let Some(value) = function_call_that_returns_a_result() {
   // value is available one level nested
}
```

Other methods are open to consideration too. I want to avoid having to check the same optional twice though, otherwise, I would just check it once, print the error, then unwrap() after having guaranteed that it does not contain error. However, that method feels clunky.

Comment: why not just ? `let result = func_call().map_err(|e| format!("Error: {e}"))?`

Comment: @ÖmerErden This returns `Result`, which (judging by the code provided) is not what wanted, because the function returns `String`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman it is still not clear because of the `into()` . I just wanted to point that because this could be an XY problem, I don't see the point that function focuses on returning an error string but uses the Ok value, also title asks for printing the error but trying to return and also op requires something can't be done with let-else

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with `let`-`else`, but there is another construct available, the one that was in use before `let`-`else`:

```rust
let result = match function_call_that_returns_a_result() {
    Ok(result) => result,
    Err(error) => return format!("Error: {}", error).into(),
};
```

This way you avoid the nesting, but has some code duplication for the `Ok(result) => result`.

Comment: I think I haven't been using this as much as I should because I thought let else was fine, as this only unwraps if you have a return statement anyway. But I guess this should be the preferred method and let else should be avoided in general unless you are certain you want to overwrite the error message

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet here is [let-else-match](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3137-let-else.html#let-else-match), which is not implemented yet but it is marked as future possibility, this is the feature that you want. Adding here as a reminder if implementation happens at some point. it might be useful for posterity

Answer (score 6):

Printing the `Error` in the `else` arm of a `let-else` statement w/o `match`:

```
fn main() {
    let result = function_call_that_returns_a_result(); // Result
    let Ok(ok) = result else {
        println!("{}", result.err().unwrap());
        return;
    };
    println!("{ok}");
}
```

Comment: I didn't know the variable is not moved. Nice.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `let-else` desugars to match expressions and since there will be no binding on scrutinee , it  will be owned on the else block, here is a snippet to see the behavior: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=21b2fb0dc2164f189e03b77cc8fdb001

Comment: For those who are interested, here is something to read about what the compiler does with the [`let-else`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3137-let-else.html#reference-level-explanations) statement.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Technically, it is not lowered to `match` but to a more complicated expressions (impossible to express with Rust), because of lifetime extension issues. But yes, semantically you're right.